# Count of cells containing specific text

Tags: excel, count, google-sheets, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Using Excel or Google Spreadsheets.

I have a column of cells. Some of them contain one letter, some another. Say this column:

```
w  
w  
w  
l  
l  
l  
w  
l  
w  
w
```

I'd like to find the count of all the cells with each letter.

How can I have another cell somewhere else with the count of all the `w`s?

So that cell would have `6` in it, and the cell with the number of `l`s would have `4` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are many more cases than some people expect where the same formulae in Excel and Google Spreadsheets do not work quite the same, and sometimes work in one but not at all in the other. However the formulae below behave in much the same way in both:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"l") and  
=COUNTIF(A:A,"w")
```

[Acknowledgement](https://superuser.com/a/601421/145438).  ;-)

Comment: @WilliamJestes. If this answered your question, consider selecting this as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the tick next to answer on the left.